# Error when running security in Terminal

Tags: terminal, keychain, error

I'm trying to export the keychains in Terminal. This is the code I used

```
security> export -k SystemCACertificates.keychain -t all -f openssl -o goodone.txt
```

And this is the error I got `security: illegal option -- k`. Can anyone fix it? :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably copied/pasted the example listed in the man page, which actually is supposed to show how `security` can be run interactively. To fix, you can do one of the following:

- Run in interactive mode by executing `security -i` in Terminal and then just entering `export -k SystemCACertificates.keychain -t all -f openssl -o goodone.txt` when you get the `security>` prompt
- Run `security export -k SystemCACertificates.keychain -t all -f openssl -o goodone.txt` from the shell

Comment: Now that error went away but a new one came :( This is the new error. **security: SecKeychainItemExport: One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid.
export: returned 1**

Comment: Try without some of the parameters to find the one leading to the problem then :-)

Comment: OK. Now I tried `security> export -k SystemCACertificates.keychain` And got this error 
`security: SecKeychainItemExport: One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid.
export: returned 1`

Comment: This just leaves the name of the keychain. It might be easier to export directly from Keychain Utility.